# Retrieve Enum's label to form a List

Tags: java, android, enums

I have a Enum class called CustomEnum

```
public enum CustomEnum
{
    A("lbl1"),
    B("lbl2"),
    C("lbl3"),
    D("lbl4");

    private final String label;

    CustomEnum(String label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }
}
```

I want to create a list that contain the label of the Enum, after that I set the list into `ArrayAdapter` for `Spinner`, this is how I do it:

```
List<CustomEnum> myList = Arrays.asList(CustomEnum.values());
ArrayAdapter adapterStation = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myList);
```

From the `Spinner` the list is `"A" "B" "C" "D"` instead of `"lbl1" "lbl2" "lbl3" "lbl4"`, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to retrieve the labels and store *them* in the list.

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.stream(CustomEnum
.values())
.map(e -> e.getLabel())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

EDIT: The ideal way would be to override `toString()` to return the label.

Comment: I can imagine a reason to have a list of enums.

Comment: I want to have a list of Enum instead of String